# Can I call a graphql mutation inside an Error Link in the apollo client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

Hi This is a part of My Apollo Client

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation }) => {
  if(graphQLErrors) {
    graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, location, path }) => {
      if (message === 'Pleage Re-Sign In') {
        cookies.remove('userToken')
        cookies.remove('hshashes')
        MoveME('/')
      }
      if (message === 'Unathorized') {
        return MoveME('/')
      }
      if (message === 'Access Denied') {
        return MoveME('/dashboard/home')
      }
      console.log(`[GraphQL Error] Message: ${message}, location: ${location}, path: ${path}`)
    })
  }

  if(networkError){
    console.log(`
      [network error ${networkError.message}] Operation: ${operation.operationName}
    `)
  }
})
```

I'm wondering if I can call a Mutation to the the server to make a log in the database which I have created in the backend. Can I call the Mutation here in the app. Normally I would use "useMutation" from Apollo-React-hooks but that can only be called inside a React component . I have already done this By Moving the User to another page for example : "localhost:3000/test" which in that components I tried to use useEffect and call the mutation in useEffect with a seconde parameter of an empty array so that it calls once and then redirect the user where I want . but this is not good. is there anyother way I can do this which is best practice?

sry for bad English :)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Apollo-React-hooks can only be called inside a React component

Try to use ***apollo-boost***

1.create a file index.js

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import * as constant from 'constant';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: `${constant.backendUrl}graphql`,
});

function graphqlQuery({ variables, query }) {
  return client.query({
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    variables, // your variables
    query, // your query schema
  });
}

function graphqlMutation({ variables = null, mutation }) {
  return client.mutate({
    variables,
    mutation,
  });
}

export { client as default, graphqlQuery, graphqlMutation };
```

2.How to use it

```
import { graphqlMutation } from 'index.js';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

/**
 * Create user
 * @param {Object} data
 * @param {string} data.email
 * @param {string} data.firstName
 * @param {string} data.lastName
 * @param {string} data.gender
 * @param {number} data.height
 * @param {number} data.weight
 * @param {string} data.birthDate
 */
function createUser(data) {
  const createUser = gql`
    mutation createUser($userInput: UserInput) {
      createUser(userInput: $userInput) {
        status
        message
      }
    }
  `;
  const variables = {
    userInput: data,
  };
  return graphqlMutation({ variables, mutation: createUser });
}

export { createUser };
```

Now you can use this createUser function in anywhere you want